# How do I get data sets from text file in to lists and variables?

Tags: python, list, file

I have a text file like this:

```
1 2 10
10 9
1 3 10
2 9 5
```

In the first line, I need the 3 numbers to be put in 3 different variables and the line after, I need the 3 numbers to put in a list. Every two line is a different data set.

I need to get first data set, run a function with that set and then move on to the next data set.

How do I do that?

Comment: When you say `3 different variables`, what do you want to call them?

Comment: What have you tried, and what research have you done? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing/tutoring service. See: [ask], [tour], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be an example function to do this with comments of what is being done in-line:

```
# open the file with a with statement so that
# it automatically closes via its context manager
# when we exit the context
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:

    # We will enumerate the file handler
    # So that we can easily tell which number
    # is odd or which is even.
    # Note that enumerate starts at 0, not 1
    for num, line in enumerate(f):

        # Make sure no spaces, line breaks, etc. at the start/end of each line.
        # The list separator is a space (default) so `line.split()`
        # will accomplish this. 
        line = line.strip()
        line_as_list = line.split()

        # For the second, forth, etc. lines we want to grab the list
        if num % 2 == 1:
            print ('EVEN -- %s' % line_as_list)

        # On the other lines, if it has three items separated by a space
        # we will grab those three items (again using `line.split()` and
        # assign a, b, and c as the (arbitrary) variable names to those
        elif len(line_as_list) == 3:
            a,b,c = line_as_list
            print ('ODD -- a=%s, b=%s, c=%s' %(a,b,c))

        # Depending on what you want to do if there are not three variables
        # you would handle them in this section here.
        else:
            print ('ODD -- BUT NOT THREE VARS')


# ODD  -- a=1, b=2, c=10
# EVEN -- ['10', '9']
# ODD  -- a=1, b=3, c=10
# EVEN -- ['2', '9', '5']
```

The above could probably be condensed into a couple lines of code but it's been written out verbosely above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as bellow:

```
with open('the_file.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

Lines_list = [x.replace("\n","").split(sep=" ") for x in content]

print(Lines_list)
```

The print will output

```
[['1', '2', '10'], ['10', '9'], ['1', '3', '10'], ['2', '9', '5']]
```

Then you can access your variables as Lines_list[line_number][var_number].